# Twig : DateInterval format minutes with leading zero don't work

Tags: php, twig, twig-filter

Twig seems not recongnize the "%l" format to display minutes with leading zero.

The Twig documentation said "when the filtered data is of type DateInterval, when the format must conform to DateInterval::format".

So, if I read correctly the PHP documentation I must use "`%l`" to have minutes with leading zero but this format is not recongnized by Twig who output "`%l`" instead of the value. If I use "`%i`" instead of "`%l`" I have the correct value, but without the leading zero.

`duration` is an DateInterval object  (correctly set to 6 minutes for example)

```
{{ duration|date('%i') }} --> output "6"

{{ duration|date('%l') }} --> output "%l" instead of "06"
```

I don't understand what is wrong...

Comment: `%I` in the documentation is an uppercase i. You have `%l`, a lowercase L.

Comment: Gasp !... I'm ashamed... Thank you very much DarkBee !

Comment: @David you meant "Thank you @JJJ"

Comment: I'm definitely lost DarkBee !... :-) Thank you @JJJ